# Creating Grafana variable from the set of of all possible values of a label

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'd like to create a Grafana variable/filter of all possible values of a label `region` on the metric `instance`. The [query](https://promlabs.com/blog/2020/12/17/promql-queries-for-exploring-your-metrics#getting-all-values-for-a-specific-label) for listing these value is:

```
group by (region)(instance)
```

Unfortunately, when I paste this query in Grafana >> Variables >> Query options >> Query I get the errors

```
Validation
cannot parse parameter match[]
```

and

```
Templating [region]
Error updating options: cannot parse parameter match[]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To create a variable in Grafana that contains all values of a specific label in a specific metric you can use `label_values(metric, label)`. You can also do `label_values(metric{label2="test"}, label)` if you want to be more specific.

In your case it seems to me that it should be `label_values(instance, region)`, where `instance` is the metric and `region` is the label.

You have information about it in [Grafana's documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable).